# Empty price placeholder design

Tags: checkout, payment, placeholder, empty

I have a checkout form for a payment request, in which the user fills in the payment amount. This amount is used as input for the checkout as a sub-total, of which a percentage is deducted.

What is the best practice for placeholders in checkout prices? In other words, what should I put in place of "N/A" in the price table before the user enters a number?

N/A vs. €0 vs. ??

[image: mockup]

<sup>[download bmml source](/plugins/mockups/download?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fBToqz.png) – Wireframes created with [Balsamiq Mockups](http://www.balsamiq.com/products/mockups)</sup>

Comment: Are you asking which currency to use as default (i.e. $ or €)? If so, why not localize it?

Comment: Ah, sorry, I wasn't clear enough in the question. I'm asking what to use for the not yet filled in price, as a placeholder in the list, so in place of N/A in the mockup.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Defaulting everything to 0 is fine. If they have not defined a "requested amount" then the amount requested is 0, and so are all the other numbers.

Answer (score 4):

I would avoid using N/A, as that signifies that field is "not applicable". All three of those fields are applicable.

A simple placeholder would be:

> € 0,0

For every field needed.

Answer (score 1):

Try hiding the entire confirmation section until the requested amount is entered.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/49034)

Comment: Ok, I have restated the answer as a directive. Thank you.

Comment: @StacyH Can you also add why you think this? It'd be a more complete answer then.